# Why return array from array.map is returning with OR operator in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to typescript.
I am now trying to map an array and return the result. but the updated result is returning with an `or` operator

here when I hover the the updated array

```
let updatedArray: (false | {
 age: number;
 id: number; 
 name: string; 
 username: string;
 email: string;
})[]
```

From my understanding it should be an array of object only.

Here is the func

```
 const increseAge = (userId: number): void => {
    //hover over updatedArray here
    let updatedArray = egArray.map((user) => user.id === userId && { ...user, age : user.age + 1 });
    
    setEgArray(updatedArray)
  };
```

Comment: if `user.id === userId` is false then it maps to false.

Comment: `user.id === userId` will return `false` for any object that doesn't match the ID.

Comment: And just to clarify what the above commenters are saying: it's not returning either an array of objects OR just the boolean value `false`. It's ALWAYS returning an array, and each element will either be an object or `false`.

Also, why use `map` for this? `const user = egArray.find((u) => user.id === userId); if (!user) return; user.age++;` No set needed afterwards, either. The `map` call is overkill and not immediately understandable when reading it.

Comment: Why are you looping over the entire array to update one value? Use find() an update that single item.

Comment: @epascarello this is a comman pattern for updating an array _immutably_ which has lots of benefits, but I'm guessing in this case it's inteded to play nice with React state which assumes immutability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&&` operator works by evaluating the expression on the left first. If it's falsy, then return that value. If its truthy then evaluate the expression on the right and return it.

```
user.id === userId && { ...user, age : user.age + 1 }
```

In this case the expression on the left returns a `boolean`. So either the left express evaluates `false` and `false` is returned, or it evaluates `true` and it returns your user object with the age change.

So `false | MyUserType` is the type that the function you passed to `map` actually returns. The result would be an array of all `false` values expect the one that matched the user id, and that would be the user object with the age change.

---

You probably want a ternary instead:

```
egArray.map((user) => (
  user.id === userId
    ? { ...user, age : user.age + 1 } // found the user to make older!
    : user // some other user.
   
));
```

This way every iteration of the loop return a valid user object.

Comment: Thanks. I am used to using `&&` while in `React without ts` because my senior will told me to remove unnecessary code.

Comment: That _can_ be a nice shortcut in React, but `map`ping through data like this isn't the same thing. Every iteration of `map` must return a specific value. Web based React just knows how to handle rendering `false` as having no output.